# regex: negate a group with condition

Tags: python, regex

is it possible to match strings if a group is not present between a starting and end position, except if the group is followed by a certain character e.g. '§'?

```
# match if '\.\s' is not present between 'start' and 'end'
re.search(r'start((?!\.\s).)*end', string)
```

for example those two strings should match:

```
string = 'start abc abc abc.end. '
string = 'start abc abc abc. §end '
```

but this string shouldn't match:

```
string = 'start abc abc abc. end. '
```

a solution would be to set a word boundary: `start((?!\.\s\b).)*end`
but i am specifically looking to set a specific character that may be followed be the negated group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add *another* negative lookahead after `\.\s`

```
start((?!\.\s(?!§)).)*end
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ylkCXg/1)